# Validate event attendees are related to account on Event before insert

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, event

I want to validate that, whenever I'm creating a record with WhatId filled (Account) and WhoId (multiple contacts available) all these contacts are related to the Account before the Event is inserted.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've checked the documentation and it's not possible to build a trigger on the EventRelation object and also these records are not available till the Event has been successfully inserted.

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but only in `after insert` trigger. Also in `after insert` trigger you can refer to `EventRelation` records already.

Detailed explanation can be found below:

- Create trigger `after insert` on Event:

```
trigger EventTrigger on Event (after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        EventTriggerHandler.onInsert(Trigger.newMap);
    }
}
```

- Create apex class handler `EventTriggerHandler` with method `public static void onInsert(Map<Id, Event> newEvents)`.
- Now what is done throughout the method. Store all accountIds to the Map:

```
Map<Id, Set<Id>> accountToRelatedContactsMap = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
for (Event event : newEvents.values()) {
    if (event.WhatId.getSobjectType() == Account.getSObjectType()) {
        accountToRelatedContactsMap.put(event.WhatId, new Set<Id>());
    }
}
```

- Fill the map with contacts related to those accounts:

```
for (Contact relatedContact : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountToRelatedContactsMap.keySet()]) {
    accountToRelatedContactsMap.get(relatedContact.AccountId).add(relatedContact.Id);
}
```

- Run through EventRelation records to find if those contacts are not in map, store their ids:

```
Map<Id, List<String>> eventToErrorsMap = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
for (EventRelation eventRelation : [SELECT EventId, RelationId FROM EventRelation WHERE EventId = :newEvents.keySet()]) {
    if (eventRelation.RelationId.getSobjectType() == Contact.getSObjectType()) {
        Id accountId = newEvents.get(eventRelation.EventId).WhatId;
        if (accountToRelatedContactsMap.containsKey(accountId)
                && !accountToRelatedContactsMap.get(accountId).contains(eventRelation.RelationId)) {
            if (!eventToErrorsMap.containsKey(eventRelation.EventId)) {
                eventToErrorsMap.put(eventRelation.EventId, new List<String>());
            }
            eventToErrorsMap.get(eventRelation.EventId).add(eventRelation.RelationId);
        }
    }
}
```

- Run through the events one more time to check `WhoId` (It is not present in EventRelation records) and form error if any:

```
for (Event event : newEvents.values()) {
    if (event.WhoId.getSobjectType() == Contact.getSObjectType()
            && accountToRelatedContactsMap.containsKey(event.WhatId)
            && !accountToRelatedContactsMap.get(event.WhatId).contains(event.WhoId)) {
        if (!eventToErrorsMap.containsKey(event.Id)) {
            eventToErrorsMap.put(event.Id, new List<String>());
        }
        eventToErrorsMap.get(event.Id).add(event.WhoId);
    }
    if (eventToErrorsMap.containsKey(event.Id)) {
        event.addError(String.join(eventToErrorsMap.get(event.Id), ', ') + ' are not related to ' + event.WhatId);
    }
}
```

In the end you'll get something like this:
[image]

Comment: +1, I might rename `errors` to be `errorsByEventId` for clarity

Comment: I have updated naming to `eventToErrorsMap`

Comment: Will check if it's also possible with a flow